# How to get Rake::TestTask to iterate over test files

Tags: ruby, rake

I am having difficulty getting Rake::TestTask to iterate over my test files.

I have a RakeFile that looks like this:

```
require 'rake/testtask'
require 'pp'

Rake::TestTask.new do |t|
    t.libs << "test"
    t.test_files = FileList['test/*_test.rb']
    t.verbose = true
    pp t
end
```

I have a folder structure like this:

```
.
│   RakeFile
├───lib
│       simple_number.rb
└───test
        minitest_101_test.rb
        minitest_102_test.rb
```

My first test case `test\minitest_101_test.rb` looks like this:

```
require 'minitest/autorun'
class SimpleTest < Minitest::Unit::TestCase

    def test_ok
        assert(1, '1 is true')
        assert(nil, 'nil is false - this is expected to fail')
    end
end
```

The second test is basically the same but asserts true in the second assert.

When I invoke the command `rake test` my output looks like this:

```
C:\src_test\ruby\unit_test>rake test
#<Rake::TestTask:0x286fff8
 @libs=["lib", "test"],
 @loader=:rake,
 @name=:test,
 @options=nil,
 @pattern=nil,
 @ruby_opts=[],
 @test_files=["test/minitest_101_test.rb", "test/minitest_102_test.rb"],
 @verbose=true,
 @warning=false>
C:/opt/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe -I"lib;test" -I"C:/opt/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib" "C:/opt/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1
.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "test/minitest_101_test.rb" "test/minitest_102_test.rb"
Run options: --seed 13792

# Running tests:

.

Finished tests in 0.001000s, 1000.0000 tests/s, 2000.0000 assertions/s.

1 tests, 2 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

I am expecting to see 2 tests, 4 assertions and 1 failure.   If I run the tests one at a time using

```
rake test TEST=test/minitest_101_test.rb
rake test TEST=test/minitest_102_test.rb
```

then I get the results I expect.

Basically the problem is that it doesn't look like `rake test` is iterating in the way that I expect - and only the last file in the `test_files` list is being run.   Can somebody please help me to get this to iterate over all test files given to `test_files`?

Comment: Can you try running it with `pattern` instead of `test_files`? I.e. - `t.pattern = "test/*_test.rb"`

Comment: Yes - same behaviour.  Only the second file that matches the pattern appears to be run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reopening the class and overriding method `test_ok`, so in fact you will get only one test case. Try to rename second class like this and it should work as expected.

```
class SimpleTest2 < Minitest::Unit::TestCase
    def test_ok
        assert(1, '1 is true')
        assert(nil, 'nil is false - this is expected to fail')
    end
end
```